# ldapclient authentication with sssd

Tags: linux, ldap, openldap, sssd

All, i'm stuck with ldap client and sssd authentication. 
i started sssd in debug mode and it says

[sdap_get_users_done] (0x0040): Failed to retrieve users

is posix account mandate for linux authentication against LDAP server?
i dont see objectclass=posixAccount when i query the user. i tried to change the object class in which the users belong in sssd.conf but still it says failed to retrieve users. Any thoughts?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`sssd` requires `objectClass=posixAccount`. It shouldn't, but it does.

If you, like I was once was, are attempting to run a mail server without having posix accounts on it, you'll have to use something else, e.g. `pam_ldap`.